# sonarqube with git bare integration

Tags: git, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube-scan

I would like to scan with sonarqube a project on our monolith project. 
Our Git Repository includes 1000 modules and we need to run analyze only on few of them. we are much interested in "Coverage On new Code". How can we specify during the scan with which git repository to work. 
According to sonar documentation we should just need to point to project base.
Exception we are getting from sonarqube 6.7.4 is:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open Git repository

Comment: No more information in the SonarQube logs?  Any details about your configuration setup?

Comment: I'm not convinced that error is coming as part of analysis. It looks to me like maybe a problem with checkout.

Comment: Sonarqube logs do not provide any exception. Our configuration setup works with git bare repository. Sonar is being scanned with ant script which provide the sonar.projectBaseDir. I see the exception is being thrown from JGitBlameCommand.buildRepository